# C++ how to return a const object from a class variable

Tags: c++, return, constants

So I have a class called MusicComposer that has an AudioSignal object as a data member called music. Music is non-const. However, I need to return music as a const AudioSignal in a method called getMusic.

In the source file:

```
const AudioSignal& MusicComposer::getMusic(){

}
```

music is declared as:

```
AudioSignal music;
```

^ this is in the header file.

I declare music as non-const because music needs to be changed before it is returned by the getMusic method. However, I can't figure out for the life of me how to return a const version of it. How can I return a const version of music?

Comment: music will be changed to const when I return it?

Comment: Ahahah @Konrad Rudolph

Comment: No, the reference returned will be const. The object inside MusicComposer will still stay as is.

Comment: @user1799156 `const` is a property of the expression accessing the object, not the object itself.

Comment: @user1799156 Well, only when references are involved. An object (not reference) declared `const` will resist non-const access, and forcing the issue (with `const_cast` or similarly) produces undefined behavior (i.e., may crash).

Answer (score 2):

C++ can automatically change mutable to `const` for you whenever.  No biggie.  It's going the *other* way that's hard.

```
return music;
```

If you *really* want to be explicit you could do this, but it's wierd code, and wierd is bad.

```
return static_cast<const AudioSignal&>(music);
```

Also, Cyber observed that getter methods themselves are usually const, which lets them be called even when `MusicComposer` is `const`.

```
const AudioSignal& MusicComposer::getMusic() const {
                                             ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in this example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A { // declare class A
  int integer;
};

class B { // declare class B
 public:
  const A& get() { // get() will return a const ref
    return a;      // here it is returning the ref of data member a
  }
 private:
  A a;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;
  a = b.get();

  return 0;
}
```

As mentioned by potatoswatter,

**`const` is a property of the expression accessing the object, not the object itself**